# Problems with connection betwen Tomcat 7 application and derby database.?

Tags: hibernate, maven, ubuntu, tomcat7, derby

I have a problem, i created a web application using hibernate with Derby database. This application for development phase is going to be deployed in Tomcat 7 server. This application consist on some services, daos and pojos. The thing is when i run some logic with a main as a desktop application it makes connection without any problem but when i deploy it in tomcat server i can see in logs the following stack trace

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
   at ...
   at ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/calidad
   at ...
   at ...
```

Here is also hibernate mapping configuration in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
            <property name="connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/calidad</property>
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>


        </mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is for me weird because the same configuration is used in both executions. Below you can see some extract of my pom.xml about dependencies for hibernate:

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbynet</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

I also added manually all derby jars into lib folder of tomcat but result is the same. By the way i am working in Ubuntu 12. I hope somebody can help me

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using derbyclient then the driver should be `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver`
`EmbeddedDriver`is for embedded derby db